# How to split time series into minutes and assign them a value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am totally stucked with this excersise and do not know how to proceed.

I have data in form of

```
ID / From / To / Value

12 / 1.1.2021 7:50 / 1.1.2021 8:20 / 50
13 / 1.1.2021 8:00 / 1.1.2021 8:03 / 100
14 / 1.1.2021 9:12 / 1.1.2021 9:30 / 12
```

I need to split all time series into minutes and find out the sum of values for each minute, so, I should get something like

```
1.1.2021 7:59 50
1.1.2021 8:00 150
1.1.2021 8:01 150
....
1.1.2021 8:03 150
1.1.2021 8:04 50
...
1.1.2021 8:21 0
...
1.1.2021 9:12 12
```

I have no clue how to start.

Could you please, help?

Thanks.

zuzana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe something like this using `apply` and `pd_date_range`

```
df_new = (df.set_index(['ID','Value'])
        .apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['From'], x['To'],freq='min'), axis=1)
        .explode().rename('date').reset_index().groupby('date')['Value'].sum())

date
2021-01-01 07:50:00     50
2021-01-01 07:51:00     50
2021-01-01 07:52:00     50
2021-01-01 07:53:00     50
2021-01-01 07:54:00     50
2021-01-01 07:55:00     50
2021-01-01 07:56:00     50
2021-01-01 07:57:00     50
2021-01-01 07:58:00     50
2021-01-01 07:59:00     50
2021-01-01 08:00:00    150
2021-01-01 08:01:00    150
....
```

Comment: then groupby `date` and sum :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang ah missed that, nice one thanks!